# Browser Huge use of Bandwith

Tags: networking, windows-10, bandwidth

I'm a web developer, and lately I've noticed that while developing on an online server, with Apache blocking all IP's besides my network to access it, I'm using huge amounts of bandwith.
In order to monitor my bandwith usage, i've used NetLimiter and Netbalancer. 
Analysing both, I can say that all my browsers (either chrome, chromium, mozilla, edge) are using amounts between 50-100mb per hour while all I'm doing is browsing my website, or even Google.
Already searched for the same issue on the net, followed a couple of tutorials to remove possible Spy or Malwares, used a couple tools and nothing indicts any kind of malicious software.
I'm currently using Windows 10 for about 2-3 months. I've find this issue either on a clean Windows 10 x64 installation and Updated Version of It.

Any help, would be very appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you confirm that it's the browser using the bandwidth? If you don't open any browsers, the usage goes down?

Comment: Yes I did. As i said, i did monitor the bandwith usage with NetLimit and NetBalancer, they both accuse huge amounts of data in the current browser I'm using.

Comment: 100 MebiBytes/hour is a lot of bandwidth? Isn't that just 228 kilobits/sec? What is the average page size (including images, scripts, css, and other resources) on your site? How often do you reload?

Answer (score 2):

The front page of Google.com, which was once known as one of the lightest (smallest in terms of KiB of resources loaded) corporate front pages on the Internet, is 1 MiB for me. A typical text results page is 1.3 MiB for me.

So averaging loading 1-2 pages per minute would easily get to 100MiB per hour.
This is **not** exceptional bandwidth usage.

Most of those resources should be cached, so a 1MiB page should only load a fraction of that each time, but if you're developing a website, you're probably hitting <reload> a lot, so you're probably not making much use of your browser's cache.

Comment: You guys are the first telling me that 100mb per hour browsing isn't much. I seriously doubt it, and all my colleagues also do. Even if i <reload> the page a lot. It is micro pages, i mean

Comment: @RUIFERNANDE5 So exactly how many KiB in your average page on your site, including all resources?

Comment: like 700-800kb i'd say. I would have to hard reload my page 120+ times per hour, I don't think I do it half of that.

Answer (score 1):

Try to browse while disabling all add-ons or themes (or most of them).  You can also uninstall any add-ons or themes you are not using.

Something else you could try is restarting your server and/or the device you are working on.  I have had many previous problems solved by a simple reboot.

Comment: This is a good point. @RUIFERNANDE5 what browser add-ons have you got running?

Comment: I'm running some extensions only, like "The Great Suspender", Dropbox for gmail, google docs, dragdis. But as i mentioned I've noticed this issue on all browsers, and I have only extensions on normal chrome.